# How To Access Namespace Elements In MXML Using Actionscript

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, mxml

In Actionscript...

If I Have an XML variable that equals this:

```
var X:XML=XML("<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="vertical" xmlns:ns1="Tools.*" minWidth="684" minHeight="484" creationComplete="Init();" xmlns:ns3="Components.*" initialize="I()"/>");
```

And I try to list the attributes via:

```
var AList:XMList=X.attributes();
```

The three namespaces, "xmlns:mx","xmlns:ns1", and "xmlns:ns3" aren't listed among the attributes!  How can I access this information programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list the namespace declarations with the [`namespaceDeclarations`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/XML.html#namespaceDeclarations()) method of the XML class.